# Change spring config server endpoint based on profile

Tags: spring-cloud

I have about 10 spring boot microservices which I am calling config clients. One another spring boot service is config server.

For dev environment all these 11 services run on localhost, config server specifically on port 8888.

Now in my staging environment (on AWS), the config server launches on a VM with IP say a.b.c.d:8888

To make this discoverable in all my other services bootstrap.yml is configured as:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: application-name

---

spring:
  profiles: staging
  cloud:
    config:
     uri: http://a.b.c.d:8888
```

The problem is that I have to hardcode the IP in 10 services here. Is there some way I can make this a central configuration.

All services are built using maven and do share a common parent pom if that relates to this.

PS:  is I want a central configuration for locating central config server :)

Comment: There is a feature that allows config server to found via discovery. http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#eureka-first-bootstrap

Comment: True. You can either have config discovered from discovery server or discovery server found through config. Benefit of later is that even eureka server config can be committed to config repo and so I am using that.

Answer (score 0):

The `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` are static to the best of my knowledge. It is loaded first and must know where the config server is located to get the rest of the properties for the application.

You just hit one issue about Microservices.  Code duplication.  Sometimes there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: How I solved this or say found a better way is that I configured a dns and gave a name mapping to my config server machine. I can at least change the IP now as long as I update the mapping. Thanks.